# Text.Regex.Applicative - Multiline Comments

Tags: regex, haskell, applicative, parser-combinators

I can't figure out the correct way to use the Haskell `regex-applicative` package to perform a replacement on multiline comments using the `replace` function. First, I'm trying to get `match` to return the correct string as a test:

```
regex = pure (++) <$> string "/*" <*> many (anySym) <*> string "*/"
match regex "/* hello world */"
```

Which returns `hello world */`. I don't understand why the first matching section is cut off. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mixing up the applicative idioms.   It's either

```
f <$> x <*> y <*> z
  ^^^
```

or

```
pure f <*> x <*> y <*> z
       ^^^
```

The mixture you have chosen

```
pure f <$> x <*> y <*> z
```

is misleading.  Because

```
(<$>) :: (Functor f) => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

takes a function as its left argument, `pure f` is being interpreted in the `(->) r` applicative, in which `pure = const`.  So you get

```
const (++) <$> string "/*" <*> many anySym <*> string "/*"
```

and now we can hopefully see why the first string is ignored.

You can't apply `(++)` to three arguments, which is why the other forms don't compile.  What you really need, I think, is

```
sequenceA :: (Applicative f) => [f a] -> f [a]
```

which turns a list* of parsers in to a parser that gives a list, and then `concat` the result.

```
regex = concat <$> sequenceA [string "/*", many anySym, string "*/"]
```

---

<sup>*</sup>Actually `sequenceA` is more general, having type `(Applicative f, Traversable t) => t (f a) -> f (t a)`, but I didn't want to get too far in the clouds for this answer.

Comment: Exactly the kind of explanation I was looking for! Thank you so much!

Comment: The above explanation is great, but I am still unsure about how to use this with the `replace` function. It seems it replaces the matched value with the return value of the regex. If I wanted to replace the matched comment with the number of newlines in the comment, do you have a ny idea how that would work? It doesn't seem like <* or <$ fits.

Comment: @20XX Ah, (not familiar with this library) but I think it'd something like `newlineCount . concat <$> sequenceA ...` where `newlineCount s = "/*" ++ show (length (lines s)) ++ "*/"`

Comment: The composition was the way to go! Ended up using `newlineCount s = take (length (lines s)) (repeat '\n')`. Thanks again!